# Simple Html Dom Does not work in this code

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Why does the simple html dom not work in this code? Is it a bug? I've never had such problems with him before.

The html code was too big to post here.

file.php

```
<?php
require_once './simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('http://sitelab.combr.co/codenotwork.html');
var_dump($html); //bool(false)
?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You should try using DOMDocument/DOMXpath instead of simple html dom. http://php.net/domxpath

Comment: `file_get_html()` is poorly coded, doesn't give any errors. Copy the code inside it (with default values too) and debug that instead. There are three parts that can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use pQuery instead:
https://github.com/tburry/pquery

Maybe there is some problem with the source site's code and this lib can't parse it, or there is issue with the parser.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the simple_html_dom code and solved the problem. The problem is because the html code is too large and simple_html_dom has size limits. It's just change define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);